# Tasks in C# problem - argument not passed correctly in a for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method where it need to make multiple service calls and consolidate the result. Was trying to use Task for this and the results were not right, so I did the below two tests.

**Using Tasks**

```
List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            long started = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Random wait = new Random();
            int waited = wait.Next(500, 3000);
            Thread.Sleep(waited);
            return string.Format("Index #{0} started at {1}ms and waited {2}ms", i, started, waited);
        }));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
foreach (Task<string> task in tasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("[Task {0,2}] {1}", task.Id, task.Result));
}
```

**Using Parallel**

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
int[] inputs = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };
Parallel.ForEach(inputs, i =>
{
    long started = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    Random wait = new Random();
    int waited = wait.Next(500, 3000);
    Thread.Sleep(waited);
    string result = string.Format("Task {0,2} started at {1} ms and waited {2} ms", i, started, waited);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
});

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Total time taken: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
```

As you can see below, the task index gets printed as 20 all the time (though 0 to 19 was passed). Also, Parallel is taking more time than tasks. Below are the results, and obviously am doing something wrong in Tasks and is unable to figure out what :(

**Task Output**

```
[Task  1] Index #20 started at 0ms and waited 875ms
[Task  2] Index #20 started at 0ms and waited 875ms
[Task  3] Index #20 started at 0ms and waited 875ms
[Task  4] Index #20 started at 0ms and waited 875ms
[Task  5] Index #20 started at 0ms and waited 875ms
[Task  6] Index #20 started at 0ms and waited 875ms
[Task  7] Index #20 started at 855ms and waited 1477ms
[Task  8] Index #20 started at 886ms and waited 1965ms
[Task  9] Index #20 started at 886ms and waited 1965ms
```

**Parallel Output**

```
Task  6 started at 1046 ms and waited 636 ms
Task 11 started at 1561 ms and waited 758 ms
Task  0 started at 16 ms and waited 2891 ms
Task  5 started at 16 ms and waited 2891 ms
Task 15 started at 17 ms and waited 2891 ms
Task  1 started at 17 ms and waited 2891 ms
Task 10 started at 17 ms and waited 2891 ms
```

With actual method too I've the same experience where the last item is being returned multiple times rather than individual results.

Would be of great help if you can guide me in the right direction.

Note: The outputs are partial. Actual output has 20 items each.

Comment: 1) Can you put the Task output first, since you have the code for Tasks first.  That really threw me off.  2) Task output is actually taking about the same time as parallel because Task 9 started at .8 s and waits 1.9 s, which is a total of almost 3 seconds as well!  3) Can you explain why you think you are doing something wrong, and what was the result you expected to see?

Comment: @mellamokb - Thank you for pointing that out, have edited. `Task.Result` is getting filled from indices 1 to 19 but in the output all of them comes as 20. Looks like it is picking the value of i at that time rather than the value of i passed while adding the task. I've read something about IEnumerable being not thread-safe and needing to lock etc. but doesn't really understand how it applies here. For 20 iterations Task took 5 secs and Parallel took 7.5 secs (but this is not reall a good comparison as sleep times are random)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to form a closure over `i`. Here's the easiest way:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
    var i = x;
    tasks.Add(...) // keep using `i` inside here & never `x`
}
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Correct, but I don't think that's called a closure. `x` is closed-over or captured, `i` is an uncaptured local copy .

Comment: @enigmativity One question - does it work the same for reference types too? i.e. `var i = x` when x is an object

Comment: actually no.If x is a reference type, all the tasks will get the same reference(ie. pointer to the same memory location) and you'll have the same problem as before.

Comment: @Radu094 - If the reference type comes from the for loop then you have the same issue as with value types.

Answer (score 1):

When using the Tasks approach, you have  a closure there on the 'i' which is why all the tasks IDs come out as 20 (ie. by the time the tasks actually execute, all 20 of them have been scheduled and thus i == 20 when the method executes).

Comment: Yeah, as u mention the value of i at time of printing is 20. Did figure that out but it didn't make sense as am passing i to the Task while looping. And the string result is added to the Task during the loop as well. i is not 20 at that time. The question was what should change in the code so that the iteration value of i is taken (as intended)

Comment: No, the string result isn't added to the Task during the loop, it adds to the task at the moment of calling the closure by the time of which `i` equals to 20 for a long-long time.

Comment: Now I understand what this answer meant, after seeing the example from @enigmativity

Answer (score 0):

Parallel is primarily intended to allow you to scale your algorithms to use the available CPU resources on your machine. If the problem isn't CPU bound (ie calling WebServices) Parallel is not the right abstraction.

So in your case it seems Task is the right choice.